# React Looping Component except one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, if-statement

I want to loop a list of elements except the first which is an `Alert`

example

```
const selection = (player, matchId, key) => (
    <ul>
      <li key={key}>1</li>
    </ul>
);

 return (
    <div>
       {(match.live) ? <Alert>This is an alert</Alert> && match.players.map((player, ix) => (
          selection(player, match.matchId, ix)
          )) : null}
    </div>
```

How can i exclude the Alert from the loop, at the moment i am passing the `key` to the list elements but the `Alert` is not showing

Answer (score 2):

Is it out of the question to re-organize your selection as such?

```
const selection = (player, matchId, key) => (
    <li key={key}>1</li>
);

 return (
    <div>
       <ul>
          <li><Alert>This is an alert</Alert></li>
          {match.players.map((player, ix) => (
             selection(player, match.matchId, ix)
             )) : null}
       </ul>
    </div>
 )
```

You could avoid the `selection` entirely by just doing

```
 return (
    <div>
       <ul>
          <li><Alert>This is an alert</Alert></li>
          {match.players.map((player, ix) => (
             <li key={ix}>1</li>
           )) : null}
       </ul>
    </div>
 )
```

..however, since you're passing player and matchId, I'm assuming you have bigger plans for your `selection` routine.

Comment: @Koala7 your edit will still fail, you cannot have a `<li />` outside of a `<ul />` or `<ol />`. I see the code change, did your question change too?